# Email notification when a comment is made in a pull request I am reviewer

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-server-2022

In Azure DevOps Server, how can I create an email notification for pull requests where I am reviewer for the case that someone creates a comment?

The default configuration already includes notifications for comments in threads I participated, for comments on pull requests I created, and for certain other changes to pull requests, but not for this specific case.

Example: Alice creates a pull requests, adds me as reviewer, and writes a comment. How can I configure an email notification so that I get an email for this comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it: Use "Follow" (in the menu "..." in the upper right corner).